# Pass menu item name to routing component in Angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to Angular and I'm trying to create an app that has two main components: a side bar and the main component.

```
#app.component.html

<div class="root">
    <div class="side-bar">
        <app-side-bar></app-side-bar>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
# app-routing.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    component: WelcomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'category/:id',
    component: MainContentComponent,
  },
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

In the side bar component i have a dynamic list with and when the user clicks on a item the corresponding component is shown in the main component.

```
# side-bar.component.html
<aside>
#HTML stuff
  <main class="container" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div class="trilha" [routerLink]="['/category/'+ item.id]">
      <span class="item-name">{{ item.title }}</span>
    </div>
  </main>
</aside>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-side-bar",
  templateUrl: "./side-bar.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./side-bar.component.css"],
})
export class SideBArComponent implements OnInit {
  categories: any;

  constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.categoryService.findAll().subscribe((data : Category[]) => {
      this.categories = data;
    });
  }
}
```

In the main component I have a header subcomponent that should display the name of the option clicked in the side bar.

```
# main-content.component.html


<app-header [Title]= "CATEGORY NAME"></app-header>

<div class="content">
    <app-category-content></app-category-content>
</div>
```

```
# main-content.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: "app-main-content",
  templateUrl: "./main-content.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./main-content.component.css"],
})
export class MainContentComponent implements OnInit {
  categoryId: number = 0;


  constructor(
    private service: CategoryService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.categoryId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params["id"];
  }
```

How do I pass the name for the routed component so I can display it on the Header?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? You might consider listening to Router Events (https://angular.io/guide/router-reference#router-events), particularly NavigationEnd, and decide if/when to change the header title based on some kind of mapping. Or, you can use a Service that you can push title changes to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of sharing data between components:

1. Via Redux
2. Via RxJs Subject/BehaviorSubject
   I'm going to give a solution via RxJs.

Create a app-store.ts in src/app with following content:

```js
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

export class AppStore {
  static categoryName$ = new Subject<string>();
}
```

Now use this AppStore in your component to emit a data like this:

```
AppStore.categoryName$.next("my dynamic category name");
```

In your header component:

```
sub$ = new Subscription();

ngOnInit() {
  this.subs$.add(
    AppStore.categoryName$.subscribe(name => {
      this.title = name;
    })
  );
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.sub$.unsubscribe();
}
```

So basically here, we are sharing data between components in a reactive way. Even you can use signal which introduced in Angular v16 if you are using Angular v16.
I hope it will help to solve this problem and future problems related to share data between components.

Comment: Thanks! It worked just fine. I was looking for a more OO solution (like passing the title as parameter for the component creation) but this event based solution is pretty cool

Comment: Another way is to take a output in CategoryComponent and listen in MainContentComponent and pass to AppHeader but you can see you are rolling data multiple times and sometimes you will be in a scenario to roll data more times from one component to another.
This is reason developers prefer to use redux but in Angular we got rxjs which is reactive in nature so if your application is not dependent on complex data the prefer to use rxjs otherwise go with rxjs